# Replace values in column with counter using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for an example showing how you would replace all the values in a column by using a counter, so the first row in the column would be xyz1, the second would be xyz2 etc.

I want to replace a whole column with a string I can define concatenated with a number which will increment by one for the next row in the column - the examples I've looked at all seem to refer to another column or primary key as a driver for the counter, I'm not sure why though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE TMP3(CH VARCHAR2(16 BYTE));
```

Insert some records... and then

```
update tmp3 set ch='xyz'||to_char(rownum);
```

Comment: seems to throw an invalid character error in toad when I add a commit at the end?

Comment: Hmmm... can you execute it without a commit? What is the ORA code?

Comment: executes without commit, ora code is ORA-00911: invalid character - the column is varchar2, length 255 if I do a select rownum from column it just returns a 1 to 1888?

Comment: I think you may have a (subtle) syntax mistake somewhere. Can I see your SQL statement?

Comment: UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL_NAME ='xyz'||to_char(rownum);

COMMIT;

Comment: Ok, I see. That's TOAD sh*t. Please execute the update only (no commit) and either execute a commit ON A NEW LINE in Toad or just press COMMIT button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5911/discussion-between-ivan-and-4rd2)

Comment: You might like to format the number with leading zeros, in case you want to sort on it numerically.